# How to enable forwarding for a multicast IP on the private network

Tags: networking, multicast

I'm trying to get Age of Empires II (AoE2) to work on my LAN. AoE2 is notorious for it's connectivity problems on modern systems, probably because it used a now deprecated network framework called DirectPlay (in DX9) and the code probably wasn't robust back in the day either.

When I host a LAN game on a computer (win7) for AoE2, Wireshark shows my computer sending a couple packets via SSDP protocol to the multicast address 239.255.255.250. This actually goes to my router (for forwarding I assume) and my router returns a packet using ICMP protocol that says "Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)". Because nothing is forwarded to the other computers on the network, they can't see the game that the host has created.

I think I need to get the application/windows7 to send the packet as something like a broadcast, or I need to get the router to broadcast packets going to that multicast address. Does anyone have thoughts or suggestions on how to do this?

My router/gateway is running DD-WRT firmware v24-sp2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is you're using wifi, by default most systems disable multicast on wifi because it can have a detrimental effect on the time slicing that wifi uses. however for just a couple machines it shouldn't be an issue.

here's how to disable multicasting but it should point you in the right direction for enabling it: [ddwrt multicast](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_IPTV_without_impact_to_LAN_and_Wireless_traffic)

Secondly make sure they are all in the same VLAN a VLAN is defined as a "broadcast domain" meaning machines on separate VLANs will NEVER get broadcast or multicast from other VLANs without some trickery.

Lastly make sure you've enabled multicasting between LAN ports I believe the option is "multicast forward"

Edit: Just a few things to add to the list in case others have this issue. Broadcasting doesn't exist in ipv6, also a machine running ipv6 MAY NOT see broadcasts from a machine on ipv4 and a machine on ipv4 WILL NOT see multicasts to an ipv6 multi-cast address.

Comment: I haven't specifically defined any VLANs and there are only 2 machines on my network at the moment. Is it necessary to have them both in a specifically defined VLAN or is it fine to not define any (I would assume the affect would be the same?).

Comment: All of these computers are connected through wifi. One of them appears to send ssdp packets by the multicast address I mentioned in the original post. All the others send it to ff02:c which is an IPv6 multicast address I believe. So it doesn't seem like anything is filtered even though they are all through the wifi. Is this perhaps some special case for Window's UPnP?

I'm going to try plugging them in when I get the chance to see if anything changes.

Comment: If they're on wifi make sure multicast on wifi is enabled on the router. as for the VLANs Most home routers don't support VLANs but I know ddWRT does and to be honest I've never used that feature on wrt but if they're all on wireless they're probably on the same VLAN. try disabling ipv6 on the machines if a machine is multicasting on ipv6 a machine that isn't running ipv6 will discard those packets.

Comment: When I plugged everything to the router by cable, the host of the game doesn't seem to do much differently, but the client looking for games is sending repeated UDP broadcasts (address 255.255.255.255). However, the broadcasts are not reaching the host. Using wireshark on the host computer, nothing is coming through. Does this mean my router is blocking the broadcasts?

Comment: yeah, either that or your host is using ipv6 (broadcast isn't a thing in ipv6). I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Ok, now the broadcasts are coming through. Not sure what happened the first time I tried earlier today. Eventually I found that the application (AoE2) then responds by trying to send TCP packets to my external IP address (the same address whatismyip.com gives me). I'm just about ready to conclude that the application can't handle modern network configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LogMeIn Hamachi?

Is not a LAN client itself but it creates a fake Online-LAN and gives you a working IP that will allow you to play with who have it.